# CodeIgniter Stacl Trace

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, stack-trace

I want to log the stack trace from time to time in my application folder.
writing to the log the result of debug_backtrace() , will cause to:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11639862 bytes) in /var/www/trunk/api.subdomain.com/libraries/MY_Log.php on line 13
```

because of the MVC structure, how can i get the last 10 functions calls/stack.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the `memory_limit` settings of your `php.ini`.

If you are using some hosting services and you don't have access to the php.ini, you can still change those settings using some `.htaccess` file and the `php_value` directive or [ini_set](http://fr.php.net/ini_set) function.

.htaccess example:

```
php_value memory_limit 16M
```

Comment: Changing the memory limit in general is a security issue, i dont want to do that. Thanks

Comment: @fatnjazzy: I know but I am afraid you cannot do anything else. PHP don't provide another to get stack trace, apart using some extension like xdebug. If you are concert about security maybe you can check the client IP using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and increase the memory limit only from your IP address.